# Five sacrifices of domesticity

Tags: mahabharata, rituals, marriage, vedic-rituals, sacrifice

The pigeon in [Sibi's story](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a145.htm) says

> one is especially bound to do so if one happens to lead a life of domesticity that **consists of the five sacrifices**. If one, while leading a life of domesticity, does not, from want of judgment, perform the five sacrifices, one loses, according to the scriptures, both this and the next world.

Which ones are these five sacrifices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is talking about householders and the necessity of doing the Pancha Mahayajnas daily. For a householder it's stated that there are five slaughter houses in their home itself.

> Manu 3.68. A householder has five slaughter-houses (as it were, viz.)
> the hearth, the grinding-stone, the broom, the pestle and mortar, the
> water-vessel, by using which he is bound (with the fetters of sin)

And to expiate the sins the five sacrifices are needed to be performed by a householder (Grihasta) on a daily basis.

> 3.69. In order to successively expiate (the offences committed by means) of all these (five) the great sages have prescribed for
> householders the daily (performance of the five) great sacrifices.
>
> 3.70. Teaching (and studying) is the sacrifice (offered) to Brahman, the (offerings of water and food called) Tarpana the sacrifice to the
> manes, the burnt oblation the sacrifice offered to the gods, the Bali
> offering that offered to the Bhutas, and the hospitable reception of
> guests the offering to men.
>
> 3.71. He who neglects not these five great sacrifices, while he is able (to perform them), is not tainted by the sins (committed) in the
> five places of slaughter, though he constantly lives in the (order of)
> house (-holders).
>
> 3.72. But he who does not feed these five, the gods, his guests, those whom he is bound to maintain, the manes, and himself, lives not,
> though he breathes.
>
> 3.73. They call (these) five sacrifices also, Ahuta, Huta, Prahuta, Brahmya-huta, and Prasita.
>
> 3.74. Ahuta (not offered in the fire) is the muttering (of Vedic texts), Huta the burnt oblation (offered to the gods), Prahuta
> (offered by scattering it on the ground) the Bali offering given to
> the Bhutas, Brahmya-huta (offered in the digestive fire of Brahmanas),
> the respectful reception of Brahmana (guests), and Prasita (eaten) the
> (daily oblation to the manes, called) Tarpana.

The Pancha Yagna (also known as Pancha Maha Yagna) are (quoting from [this website](https://www.hinduinside.com/pancha-yagna.html)):

> - Deva Yagna (worship of Devas)
> - Pitr Yagna (worship of ones forefathers)
> - Bhuta Yagna (worship of other beings)
> - Manushya Yagna (worship of fellow humans)
> - Bramha Yagna (worship of knowledge)

Answer (score 4):

Swami Sivananda in his "All about Hinduism" writes

> There are five great daily sacrifices that are to be performed by
> every householder. They are: (i) Brahma Yajna, called also Veda Yajna,
> sacrifice to Brahman or the Vedas or the sages; (ii) Deva Yajna,
> sacrifice to the celestials; (iii) Pitri Yajna, sacrifice to the
> manes; (iv) Bhuta Yajna, sacrifice to all the creatures; and (v)
> Manushya Yajna, sacrifice to men.
>
> The performance of these five Yajnas is conducive to the spiritual
> evolution or growth of a man. He gradually learns that he is not a
> separate entity or isolated creature or isolated unit, but is a part
> of a great whole. He obtains knowledge by studying the sacred
> scriptures written by great Rishis. He gets help from his friends,
> relatives and fellow-beings. He parents gave his physical body. His
> body is nourished by the milk of cows, grains, vegetables and fruits.
> The five elements help him. He cannot live without oxygen and water.
> The Devas and the Pitris bless him. Therefore, he owes a fivefold debt
> to Nature. He must pay back his debt by performing these five
> sacrifices daily. Further, numerous insects are killed by him
> unconsciously during walking, sweeping, grinding, cooking, etc. This
> sin is removed by performance of these sacrifices.The Rishis, the
> Devas, the Pitris, the Bhutas and the guests expect help from the
> householders. Hence, they should perform these five sacrifices daily.
> Teaching and study of scriptures is Brahma Yajna; Tarpana or offering
> of water to the ancestors, and Sraaddha, form Pitri Yajna: Homa or
> oblations into the fire is Deva Yajna; Bali or offering of food to all
> creatures is Bhuta Yajna; and hospitality to guests is Manushya Yajna
> or Atithi Yajna.