# What is Panchamahayajna? Why is it important to follow the sacrifices/rituals in day to day life?

Tags: belief, rituals, knowledge

What are the five Yajnas which every person should follow in daily life?
Why were Yajnas or sacrifices performed?
How the yajnas were performed?
What is the purpose of Yajna?

Comment: I think there are many posts already on this topic available on this site. You can see this one for example: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/46323/4732

Answer (score 1):

In Manusmiriti, Chapter 3

> 73. They call (these) five sacrifices also, **Ahuta, Huta, Prahuta, Brahmya-huta, and Prasita.**

> 74. Ahuta (not offered in the fire) is the muttering (of Vedic texts), Huta the burnt oblation (offered to the gods), Prahuta (offered by scattering it on the ground) the Bali offering given to the Bhutas, Brahmya-huta (offered in the digestive fire of Brahmanas), the respectful reception of Brahmana (guests), and Prasita (eaten) the (daily oblation to the manes, called) Tarpana.

Answer (score 1):

Pancamahayajna is meant for householders.

> pañcamahāyajñas(‘five great sacrifices’)
>
> Though the Hindu scriptures have eulogised saṁnyāsa (the life of a
> monk, a man of total renunciation and dedication to God) they have
> also boldly declared that the gṛhastha is the pivot of the whole
> society since the members of all the other three āśramas depend upon
> him for their sustenance.
>
> The life of a householder is itself a yajña or a sacrifice, for the
> good of the whole society. As if to remind him of this, he has been
> ordained to perform everyday, five yajñas. These are collectively
> called ‘pañcamahāyajñas’. They are: devayajña, pitṛyajña, ṛṣiyajña,
> nṛyajña and bhūta-yajña.
>
> Devayajña or sacrifice to gods like Sūrya, Prajāpati and Indra, is the
> usual daily sacrifice offered in a consecrated fire. Since they give
> us rain, crops and prosperity they have to be satiated through these
> oblations.
>
> Pitṛyajña or sacrifice to the manes (the forefathers) consists in
> offering rice balls (called piṇḍa) and water (arghya). By this
> offering they are satisfied and bless their descendants who are
> performing this sacrifice.
>
> Ṛṣiyajña (also called brahmayajña, ‘brahma’ meaning the Vedas) is
> sacrifice to the ṛṣis or the sages. Since they have transmitted the
> knowledge of the Vedas to mankind, it is the householder’s duty to
> recite the Vedas and also teach them to his children and disciples.
> This itself is the yajña by which they are pleased.
>
> Nṛyajña and bhūtayajña are actually feeding hungry human beings that
> may visit the house as also the domestic and other animals.
>
> By performing these five daily sacrifices, the householder is actually
> repaying his debts to the divine beings and the society, from whom he
> has received help and sustenance. They also help him in offsetting the
> sin he commits (unknowingly and unwillingly) while using the five
> implements in his house like the pestle and mortar, domestic fire,
> grinding stone etc., wherein violence is perpetrated on life through
> the killing of ants, worms and so on.

**A Concise Encyclopedia for Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**