# What is Panch Maha Yagna and what are 4 stages of life?

Tags: vedas, yajna

[This](https://www.hindu-blog.com/2011/09/pancha-maha-yagna-in-hinduism.html?m=1#:%7E:text=The%20Pancha%20Maha%20Yagna%20is,and%20yajna%20is%20Deva%20Yagnam) post says a few things about Pancha Maha Yagna. Also, what are the 4 stages of life mentioned here? Are they somehow related to the 4 Purusharthas?
I first read about Pancha Maha Yagna in Bhagavad Gita. Bhagavan Shree Krishna says who does not participate in This Yagna is a thief. Is this practice followed today?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Five sacrifices of domesticity](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/five-sacrifices-of-domesticity)

Comment: Four orders of life --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80%C5%9Brama_(stage)

Comment: Are these practices followed nowadays?

Comment: Not that widely followed.